# How to filter lists with same tails from a list of lists in F#

Tags: list, filter, f#

I have list like the one below.

```
    [[1L; 1L]; [8L; 8L]; [27L; 2L; 7L]; [64L; 4L; 6L]; [125L; 1L; 2L; 5L];
    [216L; 1L; 2L; 6L]; [343L; 3L; 3L; 4L]; [512L; 1L; 2L; 5L];
    [729L; 2L; 7L; 9L]]
```

And I want to filter the lists which have the same tail elements.

for example if i have 2 lists like the ones listed below

```
    [[23L;1L;2L;3L];[33L;1L;2L;3L]]
```

I want to filter them out from the main list of list but I am new to F# and I am having problem with this. If someone can help me then that would be really nice. to be more specific i want to filter 4 lists which have exactly same tails.

The lists I have provided are just samples to show the format.

Thank you

Update : i can also have this has a tuple. for example

```
 (int64 * int64 list) list)

 [(1L, [1L]); (8L, [8L]); (27L, [2L; 7L]); (64L, [4L; 6L]);
 (125L, [1L; 2L; 5L]); (216L, [1L; 2L; 6L]); (343L, [3L; 3L; 4L]);
 (512L, [1L; 2L; 5L]); (729L, [2L; 7L; 9L]); (1000L, [0L; 0L; 0L; 1L])]
```

but i still face the same problem. I need to filter elements which have the same list elements.

Comment: By tail do you mean all but the head element, or _any_ common tail elements e.g. just the very last element?

Comment: by tail i mean all the elements except the head element. for example

Comment: [[23L;1L;2L;3L];[33L;1L;2L;3L]]
the tails of these 2 lists is [1L;2L;3L] and I want to filter all the lists from the listoflists which have the same tail.

Comment: What if in your list of lists another 2 or more elements will have the same but another tail for example  '[[23L;1L;2L;3L];[33L;1L;2L;3L]; [29L; 3L; 7L]; [98L; 3L; 7L]; [45L; 3L;7L] ...]'?

Comment: that doesn't matter actually. if 2 or more have same tails then I want to filter them also. But i want exact 4 lists with exactly same tails. so if there are 4 lists with same tails and 4 more lists that have same tails but are different to the first 4 then I want 8 lists. But I am going to run this on a larger dataset and I believe I won't run into such results but even if I do then it is fine.

Comment: So what part of the filtering are you stuck on?

Comment: I was able to filter the lists when I had only tails as lists and the head was not part of the list but I needed that number also so after I added the head to each list I wasn't able to filter it like before and basically i don't know how to filter the lists now when I want the tails of lists to be same but the head to be different.

    |>Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList 
    |>List.filter (fun (a,b) -> b=3 )

Comment: that was the code i was using to filter the lists which had same elements inside but now since only tails are same I am not able to filter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of choices - this is "point free" and pipes the data all the way through. Can replace the groupBy `snd` with `List.tail` to get the answer to the original question rather than the update.

```
let data = [(1L, [1L]); (8L, [8L]); (27L, [2L; 7L]); (64L, [4L; 6L]);
            (125L, [1L; 2L; 5L]); (216L, [1L; 2L; 6L]); (343L, [3L; 3L; 4L]);
            (512L, [1L; 2L; 5L]); (729L, [2L; 7L; 9L]); (1000L, [0L; 0L; 0L; 1L])]
data |> Seq.groupBy snd |> Seq.map (snd >> List.ofSeq)
     |> Seq.filter (List.length >> ((<) 1)) |> Seq.concat |> List.ofSeq

val it : (int64 * int64 list) list =
  [(125L, [1L; 2L; 5L]); (512L, [1L; 2L; 5L])]
```

The weirdest piece of that would be the `((<) 1)` - equivalent to `fun x -> 1 < x`.
The `>>` function joins can be expanded if you prefer - e.g. replace

`|> Seq.map (snd >> List.ofSeq)` with `|> Seq.map snd |> Seq.map List.ofSeq`

Comment: Thanks allot. This really helper allot. Also I had another small question which I wasn't able to find. I am also supposed to write tests for my F# program but could not find much online about that. Can you tell me how tests are written for F# scripts

Comment: Sorry, but you put an [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.ie/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) into my head for the rest of the day :)